# QA Automation (JAVA). Как полученный токен в первом методе использовать во втором, имея общий класс

Tags: java, test-automation, rest-assured

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне правильно передавать полученный токен после авторизации из первого метода `bearerTokenAuthenticationTest` во все последующие. Попробовал реализовать через глобальную переменную, но во втором методе `setGroup` не сработало. Понимаю, что что-то не так делаю, но что именно - не понимаю((

```
public class Authorization {
    private static String token;

    @Test
    public void bearerTokenAuthenticationTest(){
        RestAssured.baseURI = "ссылка";

        Response response = given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .formParam("phone", "+78000880860")
                .formParam("code", "1234")
                .when()
                    .post("auth/phone/login-by-phone")
                .then()
                    .statusCode(200)
                    .extract().response();
        String jsonString = response.getBody().asString();
        String token = JsonPath.from(jsonString).get("accessToken");
        response.prettyPrint();

    }
    @Test
    public void setGroup(){

        RestAssured.baseURI = "ссылка";

        Response response = given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .formParam("title", "Группа губы")
                .when()
                .post("/group/save")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .extract().response();
        response.prettyPrint();
    }
```

Comment: в первом тесте замени предпоследнюю строчку на:

`Authorization.token = JsonPath.from(jsonString).get("accessToken");`

должно сработать (если у тебя тесты не в параллель бегут)

Comment: К сожалению не сработало. 
Попробовал заменить:
```private static String token;``` на ```private String token;```
и переменную token заменил на this.token в обоих методах - тоже не помогло.

Comment: Попробовал передать напрямую токен, что приходит, в метод ```setGroup``` - тоже не работает, как не работает, если токен засуну в переменную и использую токен через переменную, объявленную во 2-м методе. Видимо, я точно делают что-то не так.

Comment: Получилось передать токен напрямую в методе ```public void setGroup()```
Заменил ```.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)``` НА ```.queryParam("accessToken",  "Действующий токен")```
Теперь дело осталось за малым, как  из первого метода получать токен и подставлять автоматически во второй метод, а не вводить  ручками?)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать ThreadLocal, чтобы хранить токен, который может быть использован в любом месте вашего кода.

```
private static ThreadLocal<String> token = new ThreadLocal<>();

@Test
public void bearerTokenAuthenticationTest(){
    RestAssured.baseURI = "ссылка";

    Response response = given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .formParam("phone", "+78000880860")
            .formParam("code", "1234")
            .when()
                .post("auth/phone/login-by-phone")
            .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .extract().response();
    String jsonString = response.getBody().asString();
    token.set(JsonPath.from(jsonString).get("accessToken"));
    response.prettyPrint();

}

@Test
public void setGroup(){

    RestAssured.baseURI = "ссылка";

    Response response = given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.get())
            .formParam("title", "Группа губы")
            .when()
            .post("/group/save")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract().response();
    response.prettyPrint();
}
```